# React TypeScript - State should never be exported?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns

I have a React App that gets asynchronously its **info** with the method `getInitialInfo`. The `MessageView` is the uppermost component, so, the **Data** should live in its state, even if it will not change. In a perfect world, the `IMessageInfo` would be passed through **props**.

We need to `export` the type `IMessageInfo` because there is code that depends on this *interface*.

---

**OPTION 1** - (Flat solution with no private State)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Message from './Message';

// IMessageInfo needs to be exported because there is code that depends on it
export interface IMessageInfo {
    message: string;
    icon: string;
}

export interface IMessageViewProps {
    getInitialInfo(): Promise<IMessageInfo>;
}

// MessagesView is the upper most Component 
class MessageView extends React.Component<IMessageViewProps, IMessageInfo> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: '',
            icon: ''
        };
        this.getInitialInfo();
    }

    private async getInitialInfo(): void{
        let info = await this.props.getInitialInfo();
        this.setState(info);
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        // Message is reusable component that receives the info through `props`
        return <Message {...this.state} />);
    }
}
```

From the React's design perspective the `State` must be **private** to the component. I agree with that. But here, all the state info is **Public**. what can throw this concept way. (If the *DATA* is always managed in a presenter for example, why should it be private in this case?)

---

**OPTION 2** - (Flat solution, having a private replicated interface for State)

Talking with some colleagues, they argue that we should always keep the state private. I immediately thought about creating a `IMessageViewState` that would be exactly the same as `IMessageInfo`. This way, it gets conceptually right but we would get a maintenance issue (`IMessageInfo` and `IMessageViewState` to update whenever some of its members change).

---

**OPTION 3** - (Compose IMessageInfo into IMessageViewState. Has a private state)

So, my colleagues suggested to define `IMessageViewState` as:

```
interface IMessageViewState {
    messageInfo: IMessageInfo;
}
```

This way we are favoring *composition* (they say). But I don't see any advantage to have composition here. Do you see any? For example, if any member of the `IMessageInfo` changes (message or icon), we would need to pass all the object `messageInfo` to the `this.setState(...)`, instead of only updating the `icon` for example. Basically, it would be a more error-prone implementation.

---

**OPTION 4** - (Extend IMessageInfo. Has a private state)

I also thought about having `IMessageViewState` extending `IMessageInfo`. It seems the best solution to accomplish a state that is not exported.
But my colleagues said that it's not a good solution because we are giving priority inheritance over composition.

I think that inheritance doesn't bring any throwback in here.

---

**CONCLUSION**

In my opinion, the **Option 1** is the one that best fits the problem. Since all members of the State are public, I think there's no need to have a private State. The *Option 1* keeps the code cleaner.

Although, if I were to choose a solution with a private State, the **Option 4** would fit better.

**QUESTION:** What solution would be more correct?

Answer (score 3):

I think here is some misunderstanding about `interface` and `state`. Interface is only type of some object. So you may have separate file which exports all required interfaces for you solution. `IMessageInfo` possibly can be used in several places.

`State` is object of some type. It can be of type `IMessageInfo` or some other. `state` is private to one component. And this is be [design](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) of React.

You may consider additional option of using Redux to make `state` central to whole solution. In this case `IMessageInfo` can be exported from part of you store responsible for MessageInfo.

Example

```
// store/MessageInfo.cs

export interface IMessageInfo { /*...*/ }

const initalMessageInfo: IMessageInfo = { /*...*/ }

export const actionCreators = {
    requestMessageInfo () //...
}

export const reducer: Reducer<IMessageInfo> //...
```

In this case you'll (1) keep `IMessageView` sigle thru your solution, (2) make `state` based on `IMessageInfo` available to several components of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

> This way we are favoring composition (they say). But I don't see any advantage to have composition here. Do you see any? For example, if any member of the IMessageInfo changes (message or icon), we would need to pass all the object messageInfo to the this.setState(...),

Consider the case when you need to add more data to the `MessageView` internal state. This is the case the Option 3 is optimized for:

```
interface IMessageViewState {
    messageInfo: IMessageInfo;
}
```

When it's separated in this way from the start, it's obvious where you can add whatever data you need to add to the private state: it's added to non-exported `IMessageViewState`, without affecting any users of exported `IMessageInfo` interface.

If you are 100% sure that `IMessageInfo` has everything the `MessageView` class will ever need, you can go with Option 1.